Prevailing Winds and Circulation cells on a Discworld
Imagine a flat disc, over 10,000 kilometers in radius, made of some impossibly strong material, and tethered to a rogue terrestrial planet such that the planet's rotation causes it to experience 1g of centrifugal acceleration, simulating Earth gravity. The disc's rim is lined with 1000-kilometer tall walls to prevent its atmosphere from escaping. On top of the layer of nearly indestructible foundation material, there is a thick layer of rock and dirt, forming Earth-like terrain, and water in the oceans.
In the center of the disc, there is a tower thousands of kilometers tall, on top of which is a clear sphere containing a special medium that, when heated, glows brightly. Light focused on the sphere from a dyson swarm light-years away causes it to illuminate the surface with about the same amount of light as Earth's surface by the sun, though the center of the disc receives more light than the edges, on account of it being closer to the light and the light's angle becoming more oblique as you move towards the rim.
Because the disc has mass, it is made to rotate slowly, such that it creates centrifugal acceleration towards the rim that increases as you approach it - this can't make the net acceleration perfectly perpendicular to the disc's surface everywhere you go, but it helps make the angle of this acceleration as close to perpendicular as possible. This rotation causes a coriolis effect - as you move away from the center you are moving faster, as the circumference of a circle centered on the disc, with a radius equal to your distance from the center, is larger as you move away from the center, so there is more distance to cover in one disc rotation.
In a way, this coriolis effect can be thought of as "opposite" that of Earth - on Earth, the equator is moving fastest, while the poles do not move at all, and higher latitudes move slower and slower. On the disc, the center - the "equator", the hottest point - does not move at all, while as you move towards the "higher latitudes" - away from the center - you move faster.
Here are a bunch of calculations I made regarding the disc's gravity, climate, and a few other things: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lnxhx6fc8i
My questions are:
A) Like on Earth, air at the hottest point becomes the hottest and rises - on Earth, this is at the equator, while on the disc it is at the center. It then disperses, on the disc, in all directions, falling behind of the disc's rotation due to the Coriolis effect, until it eventually cools and sinks towards the ground. On the surface, a low pressure area is formed at the center of the disc due to the rising air, so air rushes in from all directions to fill it. However, unlike on Earth, the Coriolis effect means the winds are moving to the sides too fast, which means that as they approach the center, they get deflected in the direction of rotation. But, since this is happening from all angles, the air cannot move away from the center of the disc - instead, it forms a circle of wind, a hurricane, tens to hundreds of kilometers across, centered on the center of the disc. Is this conclusion correct, or would no hurricane form?
B) How can I calculate how many circulation cells would form, and their radii?

how does tethering it to a planet get it to experience gravity? do you mean it is orbiting it? sitting on a super massive planet?, being spun around in an arc with the planet as a counter ballance? each of these has diffrent effects on the apparent gravity.

It revolves around the planet, not at orbital speed, but much faster so that centrifugal acceleration at the surface is about 1 earth gravity. The tethers are needed to hold it at a constant distance from the planet, otherwise it would fly away.

Weird architecture. I would have expected a narrow ring, not a disc, tethered to the Equator of the rogue planet: more symmetrical. Different air circulation of course.

Circulation is going to be in the form of a single spiral. Air will rise at the centre and migrate outward from the sub "stellar" point when it reaches the walls they will be cold and chill air in contact with them, dropping it down to the floor of the disc. Coriolis is going to force the basic radial cell to twist away from the straight centre-wall donut into a spiral torus. A given packet of air will move upward at the centre then outward until it arrives at the wall where it will sink to the floor of the disc and travel back towards the sub "stellar" point slipping antispinward throughout the trip, which it will then repeat. The centre is going to be a low pressure zone as the air rises away from sub "stellar" point, surface winds are going to rush in to fill the gap, (similar to the ICZ on Earth) strengthening as the air gets closer to the centre, high altitude winds are going to be increasingly gentle as they head away from the centre until the air plunges down the wall back to the surface.
The thermal dynamics of this rotation mean that the super majority of the disc is going to be arid, cold air doesn't carry and the rising air column at the centre will shed most of it's moisture as it decompresses with altitude.

The high altitude winds will be a radial spiral, but will the surface winds, returning to the "sub stellar point" also form a spiral, in reverse? I'd imagine that the coriolis effect would cause them to be deflected away from the center, creating a vortex of circular winds around the sub stellar point - they retain the velocity of the rim, so as they approach the stationary center, their angle of movement, where 0 degrees is towards the center, approaches 90.

@cxnhgfh Sorry it's effectively a single spiral across and around the disc, I've editted to hopefully explain better, let me know if I've given you a clear picture.

So you're saying that no perpetual hurricane would form around the center?

@cxnhgfh Perpetual rain and/or hail definitely, supercell thunderstorms and tornadoes probably, hurricanes maybe, a single perpetual hurricane no. Although it will somewhat depend on the distribution of land and water across the surface of the disc.

There is one thing I'm still confused about: On Earth, when high-altitude winds stop climbing to higher latitudes at 30 degrees latitude, and fall to the surface, they start returning to the equator at 30 degrees latitude perpendicular to the equator, then get deflected west by the coriolis effect, so that when they reach the equator they are travelling almost tangentially to it. So, why don't the surface winds on the disc, starting at the rim, start moving straight towards the center and then get deflected away by the coriolis effect?

@cxnhgfh On Earth the equator has the ICZ, known to sailors as the Doldrums, where Coriolis has deflected the surface winds to the point where the air sits still compared to the surface of the ocean, no relative motion = no winds. The same will happen on the disc, the surface winds will pick up more and more rotational velocity until they're sitting still compare to the motion of the disc, only more so because the angular velocity of the surface decreases as you close in on the central pillar. As the air slows relative to the surface thermal uplift becomes dominant moving air up and out.

so there would be some distance from the center where, although not hurricane-force, the winds would be blowing pretty strongly to the side (5-10 degrees latitude on Earth). Then, as you approach the center, the winds would slow drastically, making way for thermal uplift?

@cxnhgfh Nope, the winds will have their strongest lateral component (compared to the straight line from wall to centre) at the walls, their antispinward motion will get less and less the closer they are to the centre, they'll be blowing harder towards the centre the closer they get, but not "sideways".
